# How to get the HTML of a Flash object using swfObject

Tags: javascript, flash, swfobject

To clarify:
I want to get the generated HTML without embedding it to the DOM. something like getHTML(params...) instead of embedSWF

Is there a way of doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up rewriting parts of the swfobject to get what I needed